# WP Enqueue Script Error

Tags: functions, wp-admin, templates, wp-enqueue-script

Hi I am struggling to figure out why most of scripts are not working, mostly the owl carousel. The error I could not figure out is Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at scripts.js:1

I tried deregistered the default wordpress jquery and registered version 3 jquery and put all scripts inside it and tested to be working but I was advised against deregistering the core WP jquery. So I am stuck in the crossroad and could not figure out how to make most of the scripts play nice with WP jquery.

I need help with this. Any suggestion?

```
// Enqueue scripts and styles.
function twenty_two_scripts() {
    // LOAD STYLE HERE
    $the_theme = wp_get_theme();
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twenty_two-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwo-custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/main.css', array(), $the_theme->get( 'Version' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owlcarosel-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/components/owl-carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css', array(), $the_theme->get( 'Version' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owlcarosel-default', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/components/owl-carousel/assets/owl.theme.default.css', array(), $the_theme->get( 'Version' ) );

//LOAD SCRIPT HERE
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twenty_two-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20151215', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twenty_two-toggle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/toggle.js', array(), '20151215', true );
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'twenty_two-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151215', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array(), true);
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'iotheme-foundation-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/foundation.js', array('jquery'), '6.x.x', true );
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'tt-cookie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/components/cookie/_cookie.js', array(), true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'iotheme-custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/components/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery'), false);
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'social-instagram', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/components/social/instagram-feed.js', array(), true);
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'sticky', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/components/sticky/sticky.min.js', array(), true);
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'map-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/components/map/google-map.js', array(), true);
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'google-map', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCclcoKgxMQx_C_XbcnVNmkRIHBk5xWwU4', array(), true);
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'compare', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/components/before-and-after/before-and-after.js', array(), true);

/*
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
  wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.min.js', false, null);
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

}
*/
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `$` for jQuery in your scripts? WordPress runs jQuery in 'no conflict' mode, so you need to use `jQuery` instead.

Comment: Yes I am trying to use $ for jquery but I lack deep jquery knowledge.  Can you please elaborate "need to use jquery instead? My WP installation already got jquery in the header..

Comment: I mean literally use the word `jQuery` in place of `$` in your code. Look up ‘jQuery no conflict mode’.

Comment: I understood now. The rotation banner is working when I replace $ to jQuery. Thank you Jacob.

Comment: You don't have to replace it - you can wrap your code with function and pass $ as param. And one more thing - you should set dependencies for your scripts.js file (currently they're empty, so your script may be loaded before jquery).